# How do I query within `<template>` element?

Tags: javascript, html

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I not able to select the `link` within the template?

```
Found 3 template(s)
Found 0 link(s)
Found 0 link(s)
Found 0 link(s)
```

```js
const templates = [...document.getElementsByTagName('template') || []]
console.log(`Found ${templates.length} template(s)`)

templates.map((template) => {
  const links = [...template.getElementsByTagName('link') || []]
  console.log(`Found ${links.length} link(s)`)
})
```

```html
Example HTML:
<template></template>
<template>
  <link/>
</template>
<template></template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was missing `content`

```js
const templates = [...document.querySelectorAll('template') || []]
console.log(`Found ${templates.length} template(s)`)

templates.map((template) => {
  const links = [...template.content.querySelectorAll('link') || []]
  console.log(`Found ${links.length} link(s)`)
})
```

```html
Example HTML:
<template></template>
<template>
  <link/>
</template>
<template></template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```js
template.content
```

property to correctly access to template html content.

```js
const templates = [...document.getElementsByTagName('template') || []]
console.log(`Found ${templates.length} template(s)`)

templates.map((template) => {;
  const links = template.content.querySelectorAll('link');
  const linksArray = links ? Array.from(links) : [];
  console.log(`Found ${linksArray.length} link(s)`)
})
```

```html
<template></template>
<template>
  <link/>
</template>
<template></template>
```